# Could bufferedreader be used in Java to copy arxml files?

Tags: java, copy, bufferedreader

I am new in Java and working with arxml files. I am trying to copy few parts of the already constructed arxml file ("A.arxml") into a new arxml file called "B.arxml". My question was that in order to do this copying would [bufferedreader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) be a suitable option. Or should it be used only for text files?

I want to maintain the same structure of the arxml file without any changes. Could somebody please tell me if I could do this? If this is not possible could you suggest a method I could try?

Comment: Try it.. and tell us

Comment: You seem to think that XML files are _not_ text files, don't you?  And - yes - readers are for text files only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use BufferedReader since its text file.
But if you need only copy it, without any parsing or changes in your app and you use java 1.7+ i would go with method:

```
Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```